# How to copy newest file with Euro symbol in file name?

Tags: batch-file

I have a file `Staffel artikelen met € bedragen.xlsx` and I'd like to copy it with new file name `StaffelArtikelen.xlsx` into a different directory. I think the Euro sign in file name creates an error.

How can I avoid this error:

> Source files cannot be renamed on the source location.

I tried:

```
set dest1=\\serverb02\DATA\Databeheer\StaffelArtikelen.xlsx
set source=\\serverb02\DATA\Uitwisseling
pushd "%source%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir Staffel artikelen met *.xlsx /b /a-d /od') do SET "newest=%%G"
copy "%newest%" "%dest1%"
```

The result is a 1 kB file (should be +20 kB) in destination location. I expect `StaffelArtikelen.xlsx`.

Files in source directory:

- DS-Staffel artikelen met%korting **variable**.xlsx
- Staffel artikelen met%korting **variable**.xlsx
- Staffel artikelen met € bedragen **variable**.xlsx

The latest modified file should be copied with `StaffelArtikelen.xlsx` as destination file name.

Comment: Very confusing. You say you want to `rename` yet your code is to `copy The `rename` command only allows a filename, as the destination, so you can't `rename` a file into a different directory. I tried `COPY "%sourcedir%\Staffel artikelen met € bedragen.xlsx" "%destdir%\StaffelArtikelen.xlsx"` and it worked happily for me, although I'm using `x:`, not `\\server\whatever`

Comment: Your dir command in the for /f `'dir Staffel artikelen met *.xlsx /b /a-d /od'` will do 4 independent tries due to missing quoting of the file name containing spaces, only the last part with a wildcard will presumably return something - the newest of all `*.xlsx` files.

Comment: `dir Staffel artikelen met *.xlsx /b /a-d /od` won't work because you're not quoting the path when it contains spaces

Comment: Thanks for all your comments and advise. But I think your level is way over mine to completely understand. How should the code be if I want to copy only the latest file from a source to a destination and rename the file.

Comment: Filenames in sources: DS-Staffel artikelen met%korting **variable**.xlsx/ Staffel artikelen met%korting **variable**.xlsx/ Staffel artikelen met € bedragen **variable**.xlsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This batch file could be used for this task, too.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "dest1=\\serverb02\DATA\Databeheer\StaffelArtikelen.xlsx"
set "source=\\serverb02\DATA\Uitwisseling"

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%source%\*Staffel artikelen met*.xlsx" /A-D-H /B /O-D 2^>nul') do (
    copy /Y /B "%source%\%%I" "%dest1%" >nul
    goto CopyDone
)

:CopyDone
rem Other commands can be inserted here.
endlocal
```

A file/folder name must be enclosed in `"` if it contains a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` as explained by help of Windows command processor output on running in a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window `cmd /?` on last help page. Other argument strings like `variable=value` of command `set` should be also enclosed in double quotes to get all characters inside quoted argument string interpreted as literal characters.

Command **FOR** with option `/F` and a command line specified between `'` results in starting one more command process in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the specified command line. So executed by **FOR** is with Windows being installed into `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir "\\serverb02\DATA\Uitwisseling\*Staffel artikelen met*.xlsx" /A-D-H /B /O-D 2>nul
```

**DIR** searches

- in directory `\\serverb02\DATA\Uitwisseling`
- just for non-hidden files because of option `/A-D-H` (attribute not directory and not hidden)
- matching the wildcard pattern `*Staffel artikelen met*.xlsx`
- and outputs in bare format because of option `/B` just the names of the files without file path
- ordered reverse by last modification date (default) because of option `/O-D` which means latest/newest modified file first and oldest file last.

The file names are output to handle **STDOUT** (standard output) of background command process. This output is captured by **FOR** respectively the command process running the batch file.

It is possible that no directory entry matches the specified search criteria resulting in printing an error message by **DIR** to handle **STDERR** (standard error) which is redirected by **FOR** to **STDERR** of command process running the batch file. This error message can be suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL** by started `cmd.exe` running in background.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** with option `/F` processes the captured standard output of started command process line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself as follows:

1. Empty lines are always ignored by **FOR**, but empty lines do not occur here.
2. A line is split up by default into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as delimiters and just first space/tab separated string is assigned to specified loop variable `I`. This line splitting behavior is not wanted in this case as the file names contain definitely spaces and the entire file name should be assigned to loop variable `I` and not just the file name part up to first space. For that reason `delims=` defines an empty list of delimiters to turn off line splitting completely.
3. Next **FOR** checks if first substring, i.e. entire file name in this case, starts with default end of line character `;` which is a valid character for first character of a file name. For that reason `eol=|` redefines end of line character to vertical bar which no file name can contain according to Microsoft documentation page [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

BTW: Using just option `tokens=*` results in running the line splitting, but everything after leading spaces/tabs is assigned to specified loop variable even if there are spaces after first non-space character. It is very unusual that a file name starts with one or more spaces, but it is possible. `tokens=*` would assign the file name without the leading spaces to loop variable `I` and further processing fails because of file with missing spaces at beginning of file name is not found or in worst case a different file is processed having same file name as file to process after the removed leading spaces.

So on first iteration of the loop the file name of newest file found by **DIR** is assigned to the loop variable `I` without path. This file is copied as binary file to destination directory with new file name `StaffelArtikelen.xlsx` and overwriting in destination directory a file existing there already with same file name without prompting user.

**Note:** The file copy can fail if

- source file data cannot be read because of missing file reading permissions or
- source file is currently opened by an application which prevents reading the file data while opened by the application or
- destination file cannot be written because of missing file writing permissions or
- destination file exists already and is currently opened by an application which prevents overwriting the file data while opened by the application.

The provided batch file contains no check on file copy being successful or failed.

The command **GOTO** is used to exit the loop after newest file is copied to ignore all other file names output by **DIR** and continue batch file processing below the line with label `CopyDone`.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with file names containing spaces, you **have to** double quote them.

Otherwise `dir` will treat the space separated parts as individual items to list

1. Staffel
2. artikelen
3. met
4. *.xlsx

As there are presumably no files without extension `Staffel`, `artikelen`, `met` only `*.xlsx` will return the newest of ***ALL*** present excel files and
as you are not showing the source file in your batch it is copied to the new name without being noticed.

## This should do as expected:

```
set dest1=\\serverb02\DATA\Databeheer\StaffelArtikelen.xlsx
set source=\\serverb02\DATA\Uitwisseling
pushd "%source%"
set "newest="
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir "Staffel artikelen met *.xlsx" /b /a-d /od') do SET "newest=%%G"
if defined newest (
    copy "%newest%" "%dest1%"
) else (
    Echo no file found matching "Staffel artikelen met *.xlsx"
)
```